# R introduces <NA>

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to solve a problem from Data camp Introduction to R. THE Statement of the problem is below

> As a data analyst, you decide to join Rways, a new airline that only offers flights and services based on data-driven decisions. Business is going well, and the management is considering to extend the offer from only economy class to business and first class as well. You are supposed to process the results of a questionnaire that polls for the preferred class of the respondents. The results for 50 of these respondents can be found in a character vector fly_class.
>
> Convert the fly_class vector to a factor, fly_class_factor. The factor
>   levels should be "economy", "business" and "first". Order the factors
>   if this makes sense in this context.

The fly class vector contains

```
> > fly_class
[1] "eco" "bus" "eco" "bus" "fir" "eco" "eco" "bus" "eco" "eco" "fir" "eco"
[13] "eco" "eco" "eco" "bus" "eco" "eco" "eco" "fir" "bus" "eco" "eco" "fir"
[25] "eco" "bus" "eco" "eco" "eco" "eco" "fir" "fir" "eco" "bus" "eco" "eco"
[37] "bus" "eco" "eco" "eco" "eco" "eco" "eco" "eco" "eco" "eco" "eco" "eco"
[49] "eco" "bus"
```

When I try try the below snippet, R introduces the  the factor. I need to know why its being introduced.

```
> fly_class_factor <- factor(fly_class, ordered = TRUE, levels = c("economy", "business", "first"), labels = c("eco", "bus", "fir"))
> fly_class_factor
 [1] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[16] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[31] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[46] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
Levels: eco < bus < fir
```

Comment: You have to provide the correct levels and rename the levels later. Maybe there are better solutions, not sure

Comment: You just have to swap the levels and labels in your factor() function

Comment: changed, but no expected result

Comment: Are you sure?  Compare your code above, your change by Gaurav's advice, and my answer below.

Comment: Not quite.  `levels = c("eco", "bus", "fir")` and `labels = c("economy", "business", "first")`.  That's a tough difference to spot.

Comment: Why did R introduce <NA>? any idea?

Comment: I am also doing this course. I answered the question fly_class_factor <- factor(fly_class, ordered=T, levels=c("eco", "bus", "fir"), labels=c("economy ", "business", "first")) . But it didn't let me continue. I copied and pasted the accepted answer, below, and it worked. Even though I think they are logically the same. annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try switching the `levels` and `labels` arguments.  `levels` should give the current values of the data while `labels` gives the values as you want them to appear.

```
fly_class <- c("eco", "bus", "eco", "bus", "fir", "eco", "eco", "bus", "eco", "eco", "fir", "eco",
"eco", "eco", "eco", "bus", "eco", "eco", "eco", "fir", "bus", "eco", "eco", "fir",
"eco", "bus", "eco", "eco", "eco", "eco", "fir", "fir", "eco", "bus", "eco", "eco",
"bus", "eco", "eco", "eco", "eco", "eco", "eco", "eco", "eco", "eco", "eco", "eco",
"eco", "bus")

fly_class_factor <- factor(fly_class,
                           levels = c("eco", "bus", "fir"),
                           labels = c("economy", "business", "first"),
                           ordered = TRUE)

fly_class_factor
```